# Calling HSQLDB IDENTITY function with CallableStatement to get output

Tags: jdbc, hsqldb

I'm trying to use CallableStatements to get the value of IDENTITY() in HSQLDB from Java JDBC.

I can prepareCall fine.  The issue is with registerOutputParameter.  I get "parameter index out of range" no matter what index I pass in.

I've tried SQL snippets like "{? = CALL IDENTITY()}" with no luck.

Any clues?  Am I completely off track in how to invoke HSQLDB function routines from JDBC?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `IDENTITY()`, use [`getGeneratedKeys()`](http://hsqldb.org/doc/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCPreparedStatement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) to retrieve any keys generated by the (insert) statement.

Note that you do need to use one of the `Statement.execute...` or `Connection.prepare...` methods that will enable this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Gah.

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3530755&group_id=23316&atid=378134

Output parameters for function invocation is not supported.  Use executeQuery and grab the ResultSet.