# HSQLDB "Unknown JDBC escape sequence" in CallableStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I am using SpringMVC and I have some issues with a HSQLDB and a `CallableStatement` used like this:

**Java code**

```
String call = "{ ? = call MY_FUNCTION(?,?) }";
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(call);
```

**Exception**

It throws the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unknown JDBC escape sequence: { ? = call MY_FUNCTION(?,?) }
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.onStartEscapeSequence(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.nativeSQL(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcCallableStatement.(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.prepareCall(Unknown Source)
```

Looking at the [HSQLDB JDBCConnection docs](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/jdbcConnection.html) it says:

> ... to avoid a great deal of complexity, certain forms of input whitespace are currently not recognised. For instance, the driver handles "{?= call ...}" but not "{ ?= call ...} or "{? = call ...}"

Which leads to believe that `call` should be defined as

```
String call = "{?= call MY_FUNCTION(?,?)}";
```

This however throws another exception which looks even more wrong to me since it fails in the `<init>` and does not even reach the part where the escaping is done:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected token: MY_FUNCTION in statement [    call MY_FUNCTION(?,?) ]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcCallableStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection.prepareCall(Unknown Source)
```

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12222437/1068167) it is not possible but it is dated and looking at the [docs for jdbcCallableStatement](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/jdbcCallableStatement.html) it says it is supported.

I am completely at loss on if what I am trying to do is possible, if there is some conflict with SpringMVC or HSQLDB or something completely different.

Is it possible to use `CallableStatement` with HSQLDB 1.8 and if so, how?

Comment: Please try HSQLDB 2.x.

Comment: You don't need a `CallableStatement` for calling a `FUNCTION`. Just use a `PreparedStatement` with a `SELECT` (`#executeQuery()`) e.g. `SELECT MY_FUNCTION(?,?)` (not sure about the exact syntax for HSQLDB) and read in the value from the `ResultSet`.